# Retain only dependencies of a given package

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I am trying to have a minimal version of Ubuntu, having only those packages necessary to run mininet.

So, I would like a solution, where I would be able to uninstall all the packages from the system, except those that are needed to run mininet.

A much more preferable solution would be to be able to create a new ISO, with mininet and all it's dependencies.

Is there any program out there which is already capable of this? If not please guide me on how I can solve my problem?

**Note**:
I need to retain not only the direct dependencies of mininet, but also dependencies of dependencies and so on. The final system should be able to run mininet without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the instruction as mentions here:
http://mininet.org/download/
 you should try Option 1: to install successfully.

and it got fresh VM for mininet only :

https://bitbucket.org/mininet/mininet-vm-images/downloads

Try to use the Virtual Box and this VM for mininet.